# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): 3

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
declare var Promise: any;
function all(promises : Array<Promise<any>>) : Promise<Array<any>> {
return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    if(promises.length===0){
        resolve([]);
    }
    else{
        promises[0].then((result)=>{
        all(promises.slice(1)).then(rest=>{resolve([result].concat(rest))}).catch((err)=>{reject(err)})
        }).catch((err)=>{reject(err)});
    }
});
}
//Test
function p1() { // always succeeds, with content 1
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => { resolve(1); }, Math.random() * 1000);
});
}
function p3() { // always fails, with err 3
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => { reject(3); }, Math.random() * 1000);
});
}
all([p1(),p3()])
.then(content => { console.log("Test 2 Failed: ", content); })
.catch(err => {
        if (err === 3) console.log("Test 2 Succeeded: ", err);
        else console.log("Test 2 Failed: ", err); 
    }
);
```

when running this code i am getting this error

> (node:12624) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): 3                                                                             (node:12624) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.                                                                                                                                                      Test 2 Succeeded:  3                                                                                                                                                        (node:12624) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 1)

So please help me to resolve it!